# preact-cli and firebase static deployment

Tags: firebase-hosting, preact

I have generated Progressive Web App via preact-cli and want to deploy on firebase static

```
npm run serve -- --server config
```

Above command gives me static output. But does not push site to firebase hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have `firebase.json` file inside the project and `database.rules.json` file inside build file. Once you have these files try `firebase init` then select the database then try `firebase deploy`

database.rules.json

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "build/database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/build/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```